# How to see passenger+nginx logs on restart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, capistrano, passenger

I deployed app after ruby update, and restarted passenger:

```
passenger-config restart-app /home/deploy/my_app_staging --ignore-app-not-running
```

After that I get 500 error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.
Error id: 2426c9c8
```

How to find logs for this error id ? 
`tail -f -n 200 /var/log/nginx/error.log` doesn't show any errors
Web app( rails) also doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rdalpra thank's a lot for responses!!!
I found the solution
passenger save logs to /tmp/passenger-xxx as html
So I scp this file and open locally

At the end - The problem resolved with rvm use --default 2.5.5

Comment: Good stuff, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide a bit more detail on your stack?

If you have a load balancer on top of it, I would look there, as it might be preventing the connection from reaching your proxy.

Also, take a look at `/var/log/nginx/access.log` to see if the connections aren't being returned as successful but not reaching your passenger instance.

Adding your nginx.conf might be useful as well.

Comment: I am not a sure about stack ( It was configured not by me) Here is a passenger config

Comment: [locations]
packaging_method=deb
bin_dir=/usr/bin
support_binaries_dir=/usr/lib/passenger/support-binaries
lib_dir=/usr/lib/passenger
helper_scripts_dir=/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts
resources_dir=/usr/share/passenger
include_dir=/usr/share/passenger/include
doc_dir=/usr/share/doc/passenger
ruby_libdir=/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
node_libdir=/usr/share/passenger/node
apache2_module_path=/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
ruby_extension_source_dir=/usr/share/passenger/ruby_extension_source
nginx_module_source_dir=/usr/share/passenger/ngx_http_passenger_module

Comment: Here is a nginx.conf: https://gist.github.com/rusikf/e317c21fcecf2bcfce35593324f53a82

Comment: Could you find anything in the access log? If the request is reaching nginx, there will be a log (unless you disabled it, which doesn't seem to be the case) either on error.log or access.log.
If the request is not reaching nginx, it must be hanging up somewhere in the stack before that.

Comment: Yes in access.log requests are appearing

Comment: As i understand the problem is - in my rails app ( for example it cannot start because of ruby version update), but where to see logs of this error ? @rdalpra Because nginx access logs shows only requests without any errors

Comment: I assume you can SSH into the server. Try to start passenger manually and see what's the error message that's coming up, then go from there.

Comment: passenger-config restart-app /home/deploy/my_app --ignore-app-not-running

Comment: I am see that in  /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 only 1 ssl error for today